# how to set link in dropdown value using onchange event in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here how to set different anchor tag in dropdown different value using OnChange event in html.

```
 <form method="post">
 <select onchange="$('#imageToSwap').attr('src',this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
  <option value="http://dummy.com/images/button1.png" selected>Test1</option>
 <option value="http://dummy.com/images/button2.png">Test2</option>
 </select> 
 </form>


 Test1:
 <a href="https://link1.com"><img id="imageToSwap" class="class1" src="http://dummy.com/images/button1.png"></a>

 Test2:
<a href="https://link2.com"><img id="imageToSwap" class="class1" src="http://dummy.com/images/button2.png"></a>
```

Comment: Two elements must not have same id(ImageToSwap) in your case. Use different Id or make use of the class.

Comment: @NikhilBatra same as u said.

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h2s0qc4y/2/

Answer (score 0):

Modified the code by replacing the **id of image**:

```
<form method="post">
 <select onchange="$('#imageToSwap').attr('src',this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
  <option value="http://dummy.com/images/button1.png" selected>Test1</option>
 <option value="http://dummy.com/images/button2.png">Test2</option>
```

Test1:

```
 <a href="https://link1.com"><img id="imageToSwap1" class="class1" src="http://dummy.com/images/button1.png"></a>
```

Test2:

```
<a href="https://link2.com"><img id="imageToSwap2" class="class1" src="http://dummy.com/images/button2.png"></a>
```